# MOXy: DynamicJAXBContext handles XSD enum literals (@XmlEnumValue) incorrectly

Tags: java, enums, jaxb, moxy

**Problem:** When using `DynamicJAXBContext`, mappings for enums generated by MOXy (tested with 2.7.4, 2.7.5) show undesired (plain wrong) behaviour:

1. The values expected in the XML source correspond to `the java.lang.Enum.name()`s, not the literals defined in the XSD.
   E. g.: Given the XSD enum literal `fooValue`, MOXy expects `FOO_VALUE`.
2. Even if the `java.lang.Enum.name()`s are used in the XML source (which is already hacky!), the dynamically generated `java.lang.Enum` constants lack `@XmlEnumValue` annotations. This leads to invalid XML being generated when marshalling: Considering the previous example, the `Marshaller` would write `FOO_VALUE` instead of `fooValue`.

**Question:** Is there any way to change this behaviour for the better? I could live with Problem 1, but Problem 2 renders MOXy completely unusable for me.

**Reproduction:**

JUnit-Test (imports omitted for brevity) (failing):

```
  @Test
  public void test_xmlEnumValue() throws Exception {
    String resourcesBasePath = "src/test/resources/enums/";
    FileInputStream xsdInputStream = new FileInputStream(resourcesBasePath + "EnumSchema.xsd");
    DynamicJAXBContext jaxbContext = DynamicJAXBContextFactory.createContextFromXSD(xsdInputStream, null, null, null);
    JAXBUnmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    File inputFile = new File(resourcesBasePath + "EnumSchemaInstance.xml");
    StreamSource xmlInputStreamSource = new StreamSource(inputFile);
    JAXBElement<DynamicEntity> dynamicEntity = (JAXBElement<DynamicEntity>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlInputStreamSource);
    Enum testEnumValue = (Enum) dynamicEntity.getValue().get("testEnumValue");
    assertThat(testEnumValue.name(), IsEqual.equalTo("FOO_VALUE"));
  }
```

EnumSchema.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://acme.com/test" targetNamespace="http://acme.com/test"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:element name="test" type="tns:TestType" />
    <xs:complexType name="TestType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="testEnumValue" type="tns:TestEnum" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="TestEnum">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="fooValue" />
            <xs:enumeration value="Bar_Value" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

EnumSchemaInstance.xml:

```
<test xmlns="http://acme.com/test">
    <testEnumValue>fooValue</testEnumValue>
</test>
```

**Further research:**

The latest point in time, at which I could still find the `@XmlEnumValue` annotations on `EnumTypeInfo`s is `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.buildJAXBEnumTypeConverter(Mapping, EnumTypeInfo)`:

```
private JAXBEnumTypeConverter buildJAXBEnumTypeConverter(Mapping mapping, EnumTypeInfo enumInfo){
    JAXBEnumTypeConverter converter = new JAXBEnumTypeConverter(mapping, enumInfo.getClassName(), false);
    List<String> fieldNames = enumInfo.getFieldNames();
    List<Object> xmlEnumValues = enumInfo.getXmlEnumValues();
    for (int i=0; i< fieldNames.size(); i++) {
        converter.addConversionValue(xmlEnumValues.get(i), fieldNames.get(i));
    }
    return converter;
}
```

the problem at this point seems to be, that `fieldNames` and `xmlEnumValues` both only contain exactly one value: `value`. This is pretty useless, considering that the correct values would be available at this point by using the correctly annotated `JEnumConstant`s in `com.sun.codemodel.JDefinedClass.enumConstantsByName` instead. Since the mapping created by this method now only maps `"value"` to `"value"`, the missing values are mapped at a later point in time, here in `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBEnumTypeConverter.initialize(DatabaseMapping, Session)`:

```
public void initialize(DatabaseMapping mapping, Session session) {
    Iterator<Enum> i = EnumSet.allOf(m_enumClass).iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Enum theEnum = i.next();
        if (this.getAttributeToFieldValues().get(theEnum) == null) {
            Object existingVal = this.getAttributeToFieldValues().get(theEnum.name());
            if (existingVal != null) {
                this.getAttributeToFieldValues().remove(theEnum.name());
                addConversionValue(existingVal, theEnum);
            } else {
                // if there's no user defined value, create a default
                if (m_usesOrdinalValues) {
                    addConversionValue(theEnum.ordinal(), theEnum);
                } else {
                    addConversionValue(theEnum.name(), theEnum);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    super.initialize(mapping, session);
}
```

Leaving the use of ordinal values aside, the mapping will now use `java.lang.Enum.name()`s on one side (**-> Problem 1**) and the `java.lang.Enum`s itself on the other side. But, since the fields (i. e. `java.lang.Class.getFields()`) of the `java.lang.Enum`s lack `@XmlEnumValue` annotations, the XML created by the marshaller will also contain `java.lang.Enum.name()`s (**-> Problem 2**)

Chaning the XML in `EnumSchemaInstance.xml` to contain the `java.lang.Enum.name()`, i. e.:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test xmlns="http://acme.com/test">
    <testEnumValue>FOO_VALUE</testEnumValue>
</test>`

leads to the `java.lang.Enum` being found by the mapping, further verifying Problem 1. Now, if the `JAXBElement<DynamicEntity> dynamicEntity` is marshalled again like this:

```
JAXBMarshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(JAXBMarshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(dynamicEntity, System.out);
```

The XML output shows the `java.lang.Enum.name()`, further verifying Problem 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test xmlns="http://acme.com/test">
   <testEnumValue>FOO_VALUE</testEnumValue>
</test>
```

**EDIT:** Link to EclipseLink Bugzilla: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=552902

Comment: What is your question to the StackOverflow community? Seems you're reporting a bug, not asking a question, so why don't you contact the [EclipseLink forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=111) instead?

Comment: My Question, as stated above is: "Is there any way to change this behaviour for the better?". That is, I'm asking if anyone has experienced a similar issue and knows a workaround/configuration change that resolves my issues. But thank you for the suggestion of the EclipseLink forum, I will definitely also post my question there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** It's not possible without adjusting/rewriting `SchemaMetadata`, `DynamicClassLoader` and `DynamicClassWriter`, which is a lot of work.

**Full version:**
`org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicClassWriter.createEnum(EnumInfo)` ultimately invoked by `DynamicClassLoader` only knows about an `EnumInfo` object, which is defined in the former. The `EnumInfo` knows nothing about annotations, only the class name and the enum literals

```
public static class EnumInfo {
    String className;
    List<String> literalLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

    ...

}
```

The (indirectly) invoking part of MOXy is `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.dynamic.metadata.SchemaMetadata.createClassModelFromXJC(ArrayList<JDefinedClass>, JCodeModel, DynamicClassLoader)`, where the annotation information stored in the `JEnumConstant`s is lost:

```
        if (definedClass.getClassType().equals(ClassType.ENUM)) {
            Map<String, JEnumConstant> enumConstants = (Map<String, JEnumConstant>) PrivilegedAccessHelper.getValueFromField(JDEFINEDCLASS_ENUMCONSTANTS, definedClass);
            Object[] enumValues = enumConstants.keySet().toArray();
            dynamicClassLoader.addEnum(definedClass.fullName(), enumValues);
        }
```

In order for the annotations to be preserverd, the annotation information stored at the `JEnumConstant` would need to be available in the `DynamicClassWriter` (e. g. by extending `EnumInfo`) and the implementation of `org.eclipse.persistence.dynamic.DynamicClassWriter.createEnum(EnumInfo)` would need to be adjusted to write the byte code representing the annotations.